# Use window.open in a Nuxt store (vuex)

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I'm using Nuxt.js and I want to open a window modal using `window.open()` in a Vuex store.

This is my store code:

```js
export const state = () => ({
  popup: null
})

export const mutations = {
  openPopup (state, url) {
    state.popup = window.open(url, '', 'width=500,height=776')
    state.popup.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.closePopup)
  },
  closePopup (state) {
    if (state.popup) {
      state.popup.close()
      state.popup = null
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I call `$store.commit('store-name/openPopup', item.url)`, I get the below error:

(I call that function with `v-on:click` in a element generate with `v-for` and every item has a unique url)

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at _traverse (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:2122)
    at _traverse (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:2122)
    at _traverse (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:2122)
    at _traverse (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:2122)
    at _traverse (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:2122)
    at _traverse (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:2122)
    at _traverse (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:2122)
    at _traverse (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:2122)
    at _traverse (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:2122)
    at _traverse (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:2122)
_callee$ @ client.js?06a0:103
```

Does anyone know the cause of this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you can think of an another way to solve your problem or add this to your Vuex.

```
// store/index.js
export const strict = false
```

This disables Vuex's [strict mode](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/strict.html). That means Vuex state can be mutated outside of mutations.
**Note:** Nuxt.js automatically disables strict mode in production but keeps it enabled in developer mode. If you add this line of code to your code, it disables strict mode in developer mode. So it's safe.

**Sidenote:** this line of code won't do anything:

```
state.popup.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.closePopup)
```

Why? Because `this.closePopup` is not a function. So the `closePopup` function won't be called if  the `beforeunload` event occurs. To fix that, replace that line of code with this:

```
state.popup.addEventListener('beforeunload', this._mutations.closePopup[0])
```

Comment: I have read that the strict mode becomes "heavy" when you do big operations in the store, thing that I don't. So can I use it in production without negative effects?

Comment: @alex3025 I made I mistake. It's the opposite of what I have written. It's not recommended to **enable** the strict mode in production. Also, Nuxt.js automatically disables strict mode in production, so there is nothing to worry about. Just add `export const strict = false` to your `index.js`.

Comment: But when I go in production, the issue will show up?

Comment: @alex3025 Happy I could help!

Comment: @alex3025 I'm glad it worked. You can now accept the answer :)

Comment: Yeah, but one thing, about the `closeUp` function, I didn't get how to fix that

Comment: @alex3025 `this.closePopup` is simply not a function so when the event `beforeunload` would occur it would do nothing. To fix that you can just replace it with `this._mutations.closePopup[0]` because that's where the `closePopup` function is. That's it.

Comment: But you said that that method is not raccomended .-.

Comment: Because mutations are supposed to do **only one** thing. And adding the event listener is a second thing. So I have written that you should rewrite it using an action because you are supposed to call mutations from actions. And since you would have two mutations you would  call them from the action. But I came to the conclusion that in this case it's alright to not use actions and do what is *now* written in the answer.